# Proof of a Field Extensions Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-verification

Consider the following result.

**Theorem :** Let $E/F$ be a finite field extension of degree $n$ and let $V$ be a vector space over $E$. Then
$$
\dim_F V = [E:F] \dim_E V.
$$

Now, it seems like a standard proof of this theorem begins with :

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $V$ over $E$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be a basis of $E/F$. We show that
>   $$ W := \{ cb : c \in \mathcal{C}, b \in \mathcal{B} \} $$
>   is a basis of $V$ over $F$.

**Question :** Would the following (shorter) proof be correct ?

> Let $k := \dim_E V$. If $k$ is infinite then clearly $\dim_F V$ is infinite. Hence suppose $k < \infty$. Then
>   $$V \cong \overbrace{E \oplus E \cdots \oplus}^{k \text{ times}} E =: E^{\oplus_k}$$
>   and since
>   $$E \cong F^{\oplus_{[E:F]}},$$
>   we have
>   $$V \cong \left( F^{\oplus_{[E:F]}} \right)^{\oplus_k} = F^{\oplus_{k [E:F]}}.$$

Comment: It works, if you can justify each step.

Comment: That seems fine. The first isomorphism you wrote is one of $E$-vector spaces, and you'd need to understand that it is also (automatically) an $F$-linear mapping. Perhaps the main advantage of the standard proof is that it identifies a basis. It may also be the case that the standard proof is "hidden" in the isomorphisms whose existence you claim but whose definition you (reasonably) leave out. Also, one could quibble about the fact that dimensions can be different sizes of "infinity" and that the formula remains valid in this case if its members are interpreted as cardinal numbers.

Comment: The isomorphism of a vector space over $F$ of dimension $n$ is precisely given by choosing a basis, so this is fundamentally the same proof, the only difference is that you suppress the explicit isomorphism, and the other proof makes it explicit.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, in this case I don't think I want to distinguish between the different sizes of infinity. So basically would I be right to say that the standard proof *justifies* that isomorphisms behave well with $\oplus$ ? So in the proof I suggest I would have to take this as already known otherwise it is incomplete ?

Comment: Well, the isomorphisms you wrote are well-known facts. They're also more general, as they apply to vector spaces, not just this specific situation. So I'd hesitate to call the proof incomplete for that reason. In many ways your proof is preferable to the standard one, because it goes straight to the heart of the matter. That being said, there are situations where you'll want to know an $F$-basis of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. But to be precise, you should always specify the category you are working in. For example, $E \cong F^n$ (where $n:=[E:F]$) is not correct as rings, but rather as $F$-vector spaces. Since $V \cong E^k$ as $E$-vector spaces also implies $V \cong E^k$ as $F$-vector spaces, it follows in fact $V \cong F^{nk}$ as $F$-vector spaces.

Notice that, going through the proof, this also produces an $F$-basis of $V$ out of an $F$-basis of $E$ and an $E$-basis of $V$ (by taking products). The common proof just writes down this set and proves that it is a basis, which is basically just a repetition of $(F^n)^k \cong F^{nk}$. It is good that you just use this general fact.